# Login to Sharepoint Automatically

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

Currently looking to have a computer soley dedicated to task scheduler and excel to upload files to Sharepoint online. My question though. Is there a way to set up a automated script that would connect to sharepoint online with a specific user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) to be installed on the machine running the script.

Below is demonstrates how to connect to SharePoint Online via CSOM in PowerShell:

```
$UserName = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/"
$Password = ""

Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 


if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Password)) {
   $SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password" -AsSecureString 
}
else {
   $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
}



$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,$SecurePassword)
$Context.Credentials = $Credentials
```

You could find the PowerShell script for uploading files to a Document Library using CSOM [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fromthefield/archive/2014/02/19/office365-script-to-upload-files-to-a-document-library-using-csom.aspx)

Comment: Using this would the entire computer be logged into Sharepoint or just the powershell. If the entire computer is I can just run macros from Excel to upload files

Comment: Michael, this script is supposed will be executed remotely (via PowerShell)

Comment: After it is executed in Powershell though. Will Internet Explorer be logged in? Or will only powershell be logged in?